# undefined reference to function nanomsg

Tags: cmake, embedded-linux, yocto, ld, ldflags

Treating as Server code:

1. I have created an shared library,which contains nanomsg package functionality.
2. Adding `DEPENDS += "nanomsg"` in bb file. (Without this `<nanomsg/*.h>` gives "no such file are directory" errors).
3. Server will send some data to client via shared library(using nanomsg IPC).

Treating as Stand alone application code:

4. Application code calls the shared lib functionality, such that recieves data from server.
5. Uses `target_link_libraries` for the shared library and include directories.
6. while using bitbake

   ```
   .. undefined reference 'nn_send' ... nn_socket  ld: exit 1 status issues are
   ```

   seen.

Please help me on this.

`CMakeList.txt`:

1. nanomsg code path in project dir:

   ```
   include_directories(${XXXXX_SRC}thirdparty/nanomsg/src)
   ```
2. shared lib created in other project dir:

   ```
   include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/xxxxx)
   ```

Test app name - nn_client:

3.

```
set(
   COMPONENT_EXECUTABLE_NN_CLI
   "nn_client"
)
```

Linking the shared lib with my source file

4.

```
target_link_libraries(${COMPONENT_EXECUTABLE_NN_CLI}
                 ptpnnmsg
                ${EXTRA_LIBS}
```

)

5. Since above one is not working added below one as an addon - where sharednnmsg located.

   ```
   target_link_libraries(${COMPONENT_EXECUTABLE_NN_CLI} -L/../../../xxx/)
   ```
6. ```
    install(TARGETS ${COMPONENT_EXECUTABLE_NN_CLI}
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
   ```

Instead of point-6 as above tried as

```
install(TARGETS nn_client
       RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)
```

errors while doing bitbake:

```
../../../../xxxx/libptpnnmsg.so: undefined reference to `nn_recv'
../../../../xxxx/libptpnnmsg.so: undefined reference to `nn_freemsg'
../../../../xxxx/libptpnnmsg.so: undefined reference to `nn_bind'
../../../../xxxx/libptpnnmsg.so: undefined reference to `nn_shutdown'
../../../../xxxx/libptpnnmsg.so: undefined reference to `nn_send'
../../../../xxxx/libptpnnmsg.so: undefined reference to `nn_connect'
../../../../xxxx/libptpnnmsg.so: undefined reference to `nn_socket'
../../../../xxxx/libptpnnmsg.so: undefined reference to `nn_strerror'
../../../../xxxx/libptpnnmsg.so: undefined reference to `nn_errno'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What building system are you using in your application which tries to link to the lib? Makefile, cmake, autottools, or something else?    My guess is that you only added the 'nanomsg` lib only to the yocto .bb file, but not to your application's own build config.  If you could share some snippets or even a minimal, reproducible example (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ), we can look into it and figure out what is going on.
EDIT: sorry, i overlooked the cmake tag. In this case, could you please paste your CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: edited the question section.plz check the cmakelist for the application

Comment: You probably are overriding variables Yocto passes to your CMakeList.txt. In that CMakeLists.txt, you should only append to variables or provide default that can be overridden. `CC`, `CPP`, `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` all have some reference to sysroot directories which are absolutely needed for Yocto to build your SW correctly.